# Dummy database schemas

Tags: php, database

just wondering is there any chance that their will be a dummy database schemas available for download on the net? I would like to try out a system and i need tons of information to test it from specific bugs. You know just like an ipsum generator. would there be, by any case a chance of a dummy database available. Maybe you guys have tried it. THanks

Comment: You could google to get some leaked database from one of anonymous' targets - I'm sure there are some large ones on the net. Otherwise try using google to find sql dumps which were accidentally put in folders that are publically accessible and indexed by google.

Comment: I accept a downvote, but please leave a comment why?

Comment: Wasn't me. Probably someone who didn't understood your question though.

Comment: Yah, i know it was'nt you . hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL this is a great dummy database:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html
Scroll down and download "Sakila" under the example databases.

The included SQL files do everything for setting it up, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on vendor the database already comes with some sample schemas. E.g. oracle has an employee database. Microsoft offers a "Northwind" sample.